# C# WPF Save canvas as image including its child dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, canvas

I'm new in wpf development. I have added an image in an canvas dynamically at runtime and I am trying to save that image container i.e. canvas as png image. But I'm not getting the output image properly. I'm getting an blank png image. Can anybody please tell what is wrong with my code logic.

**Code**

```
private void CreateSaveBitmap1(string filename, Rect rect)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.Image bg = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
    bg.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative));


    Canvas imageCan = new Canvas();
    imageCan.Height = 800;
    imageCan.Width = 1000;

    Canvas.SetLeft(bg, 0);
    Canvas.SetTop(bg, 0);

    bg.RenderTransform = trGrp; //trGrp is the TransformGroup object.


    RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)imageCan.Width, (int)imageCan.Height, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
    rtb.Render(imageCan);


    //var crop = new CroppedBitmap(rtb, new Int32Rect((int)rect.X, (int)rect.Y, (int)rect.Width, (int)rect.Height));            

    BitmapEncoder pngEncoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    pngEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));

    using (var fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\test\nowTest.png"))
    {
        pngEncoder.Save(fs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should force an initial layout of your canvas by calling [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx), or perhaps [InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx):

```
imageCan.UpdateLayout();

RenderTargetBitmap rtb = ...
rtb.Render(imageCan);
```

And it might be necessary to force immediate loading of the image by setting [BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapcacheoption.aspx):

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.BeginInit();
image.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
image.UriSource = new Uri(filename, UriKind.Relative);
image.EndInit();
bg.Source = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues.
It would not only affect the RenderTargetBitmap, but also XPS and PDF Outputs.
Unfortunatly the only way that really worked for me was kinda ugly:
I had to add it to the visual tree and call update layout.

Meaning I had a canvas somewhere on my window, added it, called UpdateLayout, created the export and deleted it afterwards

Everything else (for example what Clemens said) wouldn't work. So this solution is very ugly but at least it works somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You should Update the canvas layout

using UpdateLayout Method:
    MyCanvas.UpdateLayout();

Also, You should check the canvas Height and Windth must be bigger than 0;

th